# How to test for MessageAdapter Effect with BehaviorTestKit

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I'm trying to use `BehaviorTestKit` to test my behavior and the creation of the behavior invokes

```
val ackMapper: ActorRef[Ack] = context.messageAdapter(x => EventAck(x.id))
```

which results in a `MessageAdapterEffect`. However, I cannot seem to find a way to create a `MessageAdapterEffect` that will satisfy `expectEffect`

```
testKit.expectEffect(MessageAdapter[Ack, EventAck](classOf[Ack], ack => EventAck(ack.id)))
```

results in a type mismatch because the lambda, while functionally equivalent, is a different instance. Neither can I access the lambda created inside the behavior since it is hidden inside the closure of creating the behavior.

How is `expectEffect` meant to work for `MessageAdapter`?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I overlooked `BehaviorTestKit.expectEffectPF()`, which can be used to match `MessageAdapter` like this:

```
testKit.expectEffectPF {
    case MessageAdapter(clazz, _) if clazz == classOf[Ack] =>
}
```

Although, due to type erasure, I can't think of a way to verify the second type parameter of `MessageAdapter[A,T]`

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. Can you provide the full code of the assertion? :)